# Struts2 Dispatcher FilterMapping Cannot be Found

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

I'm using the Tuckey URL re-write filter which works fine. However I'm trying to use Struts2 to implement a login system for my web app. So far I've been able to bypass my other service calls so they pass through struts (they are webservlets and I don't want to use struts for them). I can hit them, however I can't access my Login.jsp. I've tried all kinds of mixing and matching with no luck. Ultimately I want to be able to use my existing webservlets but route the user to the login page if there is not a valid session and not allow access to two pages if the user hasn't logged in. But right now I'm just trying to get the login screen to show up. I get them both working separately but can't messh them to work together.

Any idea on how to make the login page show up?

### Struts.xml

```
     <struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/InsertMessage, /AutoComplete"/>
        <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="LoginAction"/>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="Login" class="controls.LoginAction" >
             <result name="success">Listing.jsp</result> 
             <result name="input">Login.jsp</result> 
        </action>
        <action name="InsertMessage">
          <result>/InsertMessage</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

### web.xml

```
  <filter>
            <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>confPath</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/Listing</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/MessageDetail</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

### Login.jsp

```
<s:form action="Login">
    <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" />
    <s:password name="password" label="Password" />
    <s:submit value="Login" />
</s:form>
```

### Error `Login.jsp`

HTTP Status 500 - The Struts dispatcher cannot be found. This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]

The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. -

```
[unknown location]
    org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
    org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
    org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fhead_005f0(Login_jsp.java:111)
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:80)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
```

Comment: ... Many Struts 2 tags require there to be an action on the stack. If you hit a JSP page directly without going through an action it won't work. Kind of like the error message says.

Comment: Can you explain what "action on the stack" means? I thought I had defined an action for login in my struts.xml? I changed my FilterMapping from /Login to /Login.jsp and I can see the login page however I get: No configuration found for the specified action: 'Login' in namespace: '' I also moved my struts.xml to WEB-INF/Classes/ with no luck....

Comment: Somehow you're accessing `Login.jsp` without an action, e.g., via your `<welcome-file>` listing, or some other way. Because there are S2 tags on that page, it blows up. I'd suspect your filter mapping(s) but don't know much about the url rwriter.

Comment: removed the url re-write section and tested, it had no effect still seeing that error.

Comment: I got it, needed a FilterMapping for /Login as well as /Login.jsp. Now it hits the action. thx Dave.